# How do I get step value from slider with jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I have a slider that I want to get the step value of with jQuery. I can manually find the step value in HTML but if I change it in the future, I would prefer not to do the same in other files too.

By step value I mean **step="0.05"** from the slider input below:

```
<input id="slider" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="5" step="0.05">
```

Comment: RTD: https://api.jquery.com/prop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use attr  on your slider

```
var step = $('#slider').attr('step')
// step will be '0.05'
```

an example [your code working with jquery 3.5](https://jsfiddle.net/lucamusa/cbajrsm3/4/)

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure to understand the question.
But with

```
jQuery('#slider").attr('step');
```

sould do the job

Answer (score 1):

use step property

```
$('#slider')[0].step
```

```js
$('#step-value').text('STEP: '+$('#slider')[0].step);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="slider" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="5" step="0.05">

<p id="step-value"></p>
```

```js
$('#step-value').text('STEP: '+$('#slider')[0].step);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="slider" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="5" step="0.05">

<p id="step-value">Result: </p>
```